# Is there a good use case for fields in interfaces today?

Tags: java, interface, ambiguity

Java allows fields in interfaces. This had some use before java 5. Do they have any good use case today?

**Can Someone give me some good use cases where one would use fields in interfaces as opposed to many other ways to satisfy the same design requirement?**

In fact interfaces an allow ambiguity and confusion in some situations. Take for eg. the following code:

Please note that I recognize that the problem of ambiguity has been discussed before and answered, but that is not my question. My question is noted in bold above. This is just an illustration of one potential side effect of fields in interfaces.

```
public class Sample implements Foo,Bar{

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello"+name);//field name is ambiguous
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample mySample = new Sample();
        mySample.print();
    }

}

public interface Foo {
    String name = "foo";
}

public interface Bar{
    String name = "bar";
}
```

Comment: This will probably be closed as "duplicate" but anyway, just FYI: in interfaces, such fields are "public static final" by default. The "public" modifier is therefore redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please point me to a questions discussing the need and utility of fields in interfaces. It would be really helpful. Also thanks for the 'redundant public modifier' note.

Comment: Fields in interfaces are implicitely `public static final`. Therefore, specifying any of those modifiers are redundant. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html. Being `final` and `public`, they are often used as constants, but some people consider it a bad practice and prefer keeping constants in classes instead, because interfaces can be implemented by many classes and therefore allow multiple ways to access to the same symbol (the constant), which adds semantic confusion.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. @fge advised the same thing in his comment. I have updated the code to reflect that. Anyway, I dont think this piece of code is central to the question, but more of an illustration for depiction of just one thing wrong about interface fields.

Comment: I use them as I would use enums, lazy I know.

Comment: Exactly my point, enums is what one should be using in such use cases, using interface would not be be the right approach.

Comment: I think enums are best utilized if used to group together some related constants. But what if they are not related, or there is just one?

Comment: @MickJ enums only appeared in Java 5 - before that it was the only way to create a group of constants.

Comment: @MickJ This was added to java long before it had enums. Nowadays, you should use enums instead of this but they can't just remove it from the language as there are truckloads of old code using it.

Comment: Because the Java designers didn't have the benefit of your invaluable opinion twenty years ago. Not constructive.

Comment: @EJP: Wow, how does 'does something have a value today' translate to 'did it ever have a value.' Thanks for the constructive comment.

Comment: @assylias before enums were introduced you could add public static fields to classes.  I don't think it was ever necessary to allow fields in interfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An interface is meant to define a contract, and constants are an implementation detail. If it makes sense that a number of implementations will share a constant, you can define it in an abstract class that will be used as a base class for the hierarchy. And if only one class is really tied to the constant, you should declare it there.

If you just want to group a certain number of constants together, you can define them in a final class:

```
final class Constants { //non extendable
    public static final double PI = 3.14d;
    public static final double E = 2.13d; //Can't remember the real value!

    private Constants() {} //non instantiable
}
```

You can also declare them in an enum when they are an enumeration (colours for example).

More about it in Effective Java Item #19 "Use interfaces only to define types", which concludes with:

> In summary, interfaces should be used only to define types. They should not be used to export constants.

Bottom line, there is always a better way to define constants than in an interface.

Comment: While I agree with what you have said, my question still remains as "Can Someone give me some good use cases where one would use fields in interfaces as opposed to many other ways to satisfy the same design requirement?" and if the answer is none, then an authoritative answer(possibly with citation) - One should never use fields in java interfaces.

Comment: @MickJ Joshua Bloch concludes in Item 19: "*In summary, interfaces should be used only to define types. They should not
be used to export constants.*". I think he qualifies as an authoritative source.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted. So if I see usage of fields in interfaces, I can safely consider it less than optimal

Answer (score 5):

If someone managed to give you a few good cases where one would use fields in interfaces as opposed to many other ways to satisfy the same design requirement, it would automatically justify using constants in interfaces.

In fact this is something we used to do in the very first versions of Java, many years back. Since then constants in interfaces have been abandoned in favor of [static imports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html), which are also no perfect and classes of constants.

As stated in Java docs:

> "So when should you use static import? Very sparingly! Only use it
>   when you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants,
>   or to abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern). In other
>   words, use it when you require frequent access to static members from
>   one or two classes."

Here are the drawbacks of using the constant interface pattern, according to Joshua Bloch (Bloch, Joshua, Effective Java, 2nd Edition, p. 98), as found in [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface):

> 1. It pollutes the class namespace with read-only variables that may
>      not be of use.
> 2. Contrary to the compile-time tactical utility of implementing a
>      constants interface,the incidental run-time artifacts have little
>      practical purpose (cf. marker interfaces which also have no methods
>      but are useful at run-time).
> 3. If binary code compatibility is required in future releases, the
>      constants interface must remain forever an interface (it cannot be
>      converted into a class), even though it has not been used as an
>      interface in the conventional sense.
> 4. Without an IDE that resolves where the constant are coming from,
>      tracking it back to its containing class or interface can be time
>      consuming.
> 5. A variable (representing an instance) of the interface is
>      syntactically no more useful than the interface name itself (since
>      it has no methods).

Comment: Fair enough. So can you authoritatively say - There is absolutely no good use case for using fields in interfaces in Java(atleast not since 2004 when Java5 was released). Which would automatically translate to - One should never use fields in java interfaces.

Comment: I do not want to express it so absolute, but i think that interfaces should deal with behavior of classes rather than with data.

Comment: Thanks for the very well detailed answer.  This is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In java, `Interface` fields are implicitly `public static final`.And they must be initialized within the interface during declaration. This can be used to create universal constants which can be called anywhere in the code (*without implementing that interface*). In java API [`javax.swing.SwingUtilities`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html) is the interface which contains only constants but no method declaration. In java, implementing such interface in order to achieve convenient syntactic access to those constants is called as [constant interface pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) which is indeed a very bad practice.

As pointed out by @assylias It could be considered as a substitute for `enums` prior to Java5.

Comment: Its considered an anti-pattern and bad practice as far as I know. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface

Comment: Using enums is generally preferred but before they appeared in Java 5 that was the only way.

Comment: @assylias - Thanks. That's the point. Why would you use and interface to do it? So my question still remains when would be good case for using fields in interface? Java 5 was released over 9 years ago.

Comment: @Mickj Now interface is not used for such things.Since Java5, programmers use `enum` for achieving such tasks. For eg. `Thread.State`.